# Programmatically creating Label that shows Slider value on each scene on ScrollView

Tags: ios, xcode, uiscrollview, swift3

im kinda new to the programming world specifically on swift.
Ive started to practice a bit and im currently working on a demo app just to explore..

So right now what the app suppose to do is to show have a scroll view, and each screen shows a different "animal" or any other subject by an Image, a Label and an Icon, on the side theres a slider with 1-5 values which suppose to show how much you "love" that subject on a scale of 1 to 5.

everything works except I cant seem to add a label to each of the screens above the slider to show its current value.

with the current code it shows every screen with its appropriate image/label/icon, shows the right Page on the page indicator, and shows a working Slider,
 only on the last frame the Slider have a Label that is connected to its value. 
cant seem to figure it out

hopefully its clear enough, thanks alot.

(P.S Im fully aware that i might be doing this thing completely wrong in the first place, enlighten me its welcome)

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UIScrollViewDelegate {


    public var sliderLbl = UILabel() 
    @IBOutlet var mainScrollView: UIScrollView!   
    @IBOutlet var secondScrollView: UIScrollView!
    var imageArray = [UIImage]()
    var iconImg = [UIImage]()
    var pageControl : UIPageControl = UIPageControl(frame: CGRect(x: 160, y: 420, width: 50, height: 100))
    var subjects:[String] = []

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.


        mainScrollView.delegate = self
        mainScrollView.frame = view.frame
        imageArray = [pic1.png, pic2.png, pic3.png, pic4.png, pic5.png]
        subjects = ["Dog", "Cat", "Mouse", "Cow", "Snake"]
        iconImg = [icon1.png, icon2.png, icon3.png, icon4.png]

        for i in 0..<imageArray.count{
            let labelView = UILabel()
            let imageView = UIImageView()
            let subjIcon = UIImageView()
            let oneSlider = UISlider()
            let sliderLabel = sliderLbl
                sliderLabel.textColor = UIColor.black
            oneSlider.transform = CGAffineTransform(rotationAngle: CGFloat(-M_PI_2))
            oneSlider.minimumValue = 1
            oneSlider.maximumValue = 5
            oneSlider.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
            oneSlider.value = 1
            oneSlider.tintColor = UIColor.darkGray
            oneSlider.isContinuous = true
            sliderLabel.text = "1"
            labelView.text = subjects[i]
            labelView.textColor = UIColor.darkGray
            labelView.textAlignment = .center
            imageView.alpha = 0.85
            imageView.image = imageArray[i]
            imageView.contentMode = .center
            subjIcon.image = iconImg[i]
            subjIcon.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
            let xPosition = self.view.frame.width * CGFloat(i)
            imageView.frame = CGRect(x: xPosition, y: -50, width: self.mainScrollView.frame.width, height: self.mainScrollView.frame.height)
            labelView.frame = CGRect(x: xPosition, y: -250, width: self.mainScrollView.frame.width, height: self.mainScrollView.frame.height)
            iconImg.frame = CGRect(x: xPosition, y: 500, width: self.mainScrollView.frame.width, height: 150)
             oneSlider.frame = CGRect(x: xPosition, y: 250, width: 50, height: 130)
            sliderLabel.frame = CGRect(x: xPosition+20, y: 180, width: self.mainScrollView.frame.width, height: 80)
            mainScrollView.contentSize.width = mainScrollView.frame.width * CGFloat(i + 1)
                       // Add subViews

            mainScrollView.addSubview(subjIcon)
            mainScrollView.addSubview(imageView)
            mainScrollView.addSubview(labelView)
            mainScrollView.bringSubview(toFront: subjIcon)


            oneSlider.addTarget(self, action: #selector(sliderSlid(_:)) ,for: UIControlEvents.valueChanged)



            mainScrollView.addSubview(sliderLabel)
            mainScrollView.addSubview(oneSlider)

       func configurePageControl() {
            self.pageControl.numberOfPages = imageArray.count
            self.pageControl.currentPage = 0
            self.pageControl.tintColor = UIColor.red
            self.pageControl.pageIndicatorTintColor = UIColor.lightGray
            self.pageControl.currentPageIndicatorTintColor = UIColor.green
            self.view.addSubview(pageControl)
        }
        configurePageControl()


        }

    }

    func sliderSlid(_ sender: UISlider) {

        sliderLbl.text = String(Int(roundf(sender.value)))

    }


    func scrollViewDidEndDecelerating(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
        let pageNumber = round(mainScrollView.contentOffset.x / mainScrollView.frame.size.width)
        pageControl.currentPage = Int(pageNumber)
    }
    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

}
```

Comment: Plus one because you included lots of detail (and code!), but what you really need is to add in screenshots that illustrate what you are seeing.  You probably don't have enough rep yet to add in images, but you will soon (if you get more upvotes in this question or if you answer somebody else's question in the meantime).

Comment: First of all thank for the answer.

Comment: Okay I got some more information that I hope will help, I deleted the first line, 

var sliderLbl = UILabel(),

Changed sliderLabel to: let sliderLabel = UILabel() 

and changed the sliderSlid function to:


   func sliderSlid(_ sender: UISlider) {

        sliderLabel.text = String(Int(roundf(sender.value)))

    } 
And inserted it into the viewDidLoad func right above the line 

 oneSlider.addTarget(self, action: #selector(sliderSlid(_:)) ,for: UIControlEvents.valueChanged)

Comment: Now the problem is that I have every screen with its Slider and Label 
but the action doesnt work(i.e moving the slider wont change the label from "1" to its .value and the Error I get is 

argument of '#selector' cannot refer to a local function 'sliderSlid'


Im sorry I cant give screenshots yet, but If some1 would like to help me in private i'd appreciate it !

Comment: try to use `#selector(self.sliderSlid(_:))`